# Chronyd doesn't synchronize: No suitable source for synchronization

Tags: rhel, firewalld, almalinux, chrony

I have a workstation VM I use as a control node for Ansible.

The time in the VM is wrong, so I tried using chronyd but the time doesn't sync:

```
[root@workstation ~]# chronyc sources
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample
===============================================================================
^? host-95-230-240-5.busine>     0   7     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? radha.parvati.it              0   7     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? time.cloudflare.com           0   7     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
[root@workstation ~]#
```

I tried also with the chronyd command but that doesn't work either

```
[root@workstation ~]# chronyd -q 'pool 1.it.pool.ntp.org iburst'
2024-02-07T10:22:29Z chronyd version 4.2 starting (+CMDMON +NTP +REFCLOCK +RTC +PRIVDROP +SCFILTER +SIGND +ASYNCDNS +NTS +SECHASH +IPV6 +DEBUG)
2024-02-07T10:22:29Z Initial frequency 20.415 ppm
2024-02-07T10:22:39Z No suitable source for synchronisation
2024-02-07T10:22:39Z chronyd exiting
```

The firewall has the 123 UDP port open:

```
[root@workstation ~]# firewall-cmd --list-ports
123/udp
```

This is the /etc/chrony.conf configuration file:

```
pool 1.it.pool.ntp.org iburst
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/drift
makestep 1.0 3
rtcsync
keyfile /etc/chrony.keys
leapsectz right/UTC
logdir /var/log/chrony
```

What should I do? I don't know where to search anymore

Thanks

Tried:
Opening the port on firewall
Manually setup chronyd with -q option